# Android : AchartEngine Weight chart layout.addView is raising an exception

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I'm trying to display wheight chart ,using the Achart Engine lib. But i'm having an exception in the line : layout.addView...

Can someone tell me what i'm missing. Because when i try to display the chart in new intent ,it works perfetly, but when i try to display it in a layout it crashes.

This is the code i used :

```
    LinearLayout layout;
    View mChartView ;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);

        CategorySeries category = new CategorySeries("Weight indic");
        category.add("Current", 75);
        category.add("Minimum", 65);
        category.add("Maximum", 90);

        DialRenderer renderer = new DialRenderer();
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});

        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 150, 0));
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setShowLabels(true);
        renderer.setVisualTypes(new DialRenderer.Type[] {Type.ARROW, Type.NEEDLE, Type.NEEDLE});
        renderer.setMinValue(0);
        renderer.setMaxValue(150);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        if (mChartView != null) {
           layout.removeView(mChartView);
        }

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getDialChartView(MyWifiNetwork.this, category, renderer);

        layout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
```

And this the logCat :

```
05-23 11:25:03.332: W/dalvikvm(28280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d869a8)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.debitdistance/com.example.debitdistance.MyWifiNetwork}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at com.example.debitdistance.MyWifiNetwork.onCreate(MyWifiNetwork.java:227)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-23 11:25:03.365: E/AndroidRuntime(28280):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: This line `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` in your LogCat says that you are using an unreferenced object. This line `at com.example.debitdistance.MyWifiNetwork.onCreate(MyWifiNetwork.java:227)` tells you where the error occurs

Comment: yes as i said ,the exception is pointing on this line of code : `layout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`. But i can't see the source error.

Comment: Well, I suspect that the culprit is **this** line `mChartView = ChartFactory.getDialChartView(MyWifiNetwork.this, category, renderer);`, instead. It appears that you **didn't initialize mChartView** anywhere, before assigning it a value (declaring it as `View mChartView ;` still leaves it as a **null** object). So, you try to assign a value to nothing.

Comment: 1-When i try to display the chart in an intent using this code :  `Intent intent = ChartFactory.getDialChartIntent(MyWifiNetwork.this, category, renderer, "chart");
   startActivity(intent);` it works perfectly ,it means that the parameters in the function are good. 2- Like you said i suspect the same think as you ,but i already used the same methode ,without initializing the mcharView ,to display other charts ,and they worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm using a slightly different code, which works - but I am in a Fragment. If you want me to, I'll show it to you, but I have to post it as an answer, because of the formatting.

Comment: ok :) i hope it'll help. So if i had to initilise the mChartView varaibale ,what should i put in ? **PS** i initialised as null ,but i had the same exception.

Comment: I made mine on the fly, directly before using it, look at my answer - It should be easily adaptable to your case (it's just 3 lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the code I'm using in a project of mine:

```
    // ...
    // The chart
    final GraphicalView cht = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(ctx, ds, renderer, "MMM");

    // The chart container
    final RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.chart);
    lay.addView(cht);
    // ...
```

Obviously, I'm using a different container, I'm in a Fragment (so remove getView(). before findViewByID), using a timeChartView, ...
So, some modification are needed to adapt this to your code.

**[EDIT]**

Try so: these lines

```
// ...
// The chart
final GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getDialChartView(MyWifiNetwork.this, category, renderer);

// The chart container
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
layout.addView(mChartView);
// ...
```

will be replacing all these lines

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

if (mChartView != null) {
    layout.removeView(mChartView);
}

mChartView = ChartFactory.getDialChartView(MyWifiNetwork.this, category, renderer);

layout.addView(mChartView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Note that now you need to remove these lines:

```
LinearLayout layout;
View mChartView;
```

Comment: Still the same problem @Der Golem

Comment: Thank you for your help :). Finely it worked ,i just created a new activity .It seems that the old one contains some problemm. Anyway it works now. Thank you @Der Golem